# Disabling Windows keys while UWP is running

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm building a universal Windows app and need to lock down the desktop so that the user can't escape out of the program. So I need to temporarily disable the Windows key and ctrl + alt + del.

I was able to add a event handler like so:

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += (s, e) => 
{
    if(e.VirtualKey == VirtualKey.LeftWindows || e.VirtualKey == VirtualKey.RightWindows)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

But the keypress event still fires.

I also found a method using what I believe are Windows hooks from the user32 lib.

```
[DllImport("user32", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hwnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);
[DllImport("user32", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hwnd, int id);
[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
```

I found some sample code [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/RegisterHotKey.html), but I think I'll have to tweak it for a simple Windows key press.

Is the Windows hook method (as used in the example link) the way to go?

Comment: You cannot disable Ctrl+Alt+Del with code, so this is a dead end. Instead, solve this problem using Group Policies. Ask questions about that on Server Fault, since it's an administration issue, not a programming one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [Kiosk apps for assigned access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt633799(v=vs.85).aspx) was very close to your requirement. This document describes how to implement a kiosk app. You could use the Lock framework and assigned access to create a kiosk app that enables users to interact with a single app on a device.

[Set up a kiosk on Windows 10 Pro, Enterprise, or Education](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/manage/set-up-a-kiosk-for-windows-10-for-desktop-editions) for your reference.